# How to create EF Core navigation property with complex multilevel relationship?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I'm currently learning EF Core and having a hard time writing efficient queries and defining my models properly.

I have this simplified database scheme and currently I'm struggling with creating a navigation property called `Foods` on the `Recipe` entity. Is there a chance to do this, without creating an extra table, which tracks the associated `food` entities?

```
  ┌──────────────┐         ┌──────────────┐         ┌──────────────┐         ┌──────────────┐
  │    recipe    │         │     step     │         │  ingredient  │         │     food     │
  ├──────────────┤         ├──────────────┤         ├──────────────┤         ├──────────────┤
  │- Id          │   1:n   │- Id          │   1:n   │- Id          │   n:1   │- Id          │
  │              ├─────────┤- RecipeId    ├─────────┤- StepId      ├─────────┤              │
  │              │         │              │         │- FoodId      │         │              │
  │              │         │              │         │- Quantity    │         │              │
  │              │         │              │         │              │         │              │
  │              │         │              │         │              │         │              │
  └──────────────┘         └──────────────┘         └──────────────┘         └──────────────┘
```

To clarify the model:

- Each recipe has 1 or more steps
- Each step has 1 or more ingredients
- Each ingredient has one food
- But each food may exists in multiple ingredients

So first question is: Can I use the `ModelBuilder` in my `DbContext` to describe this relationship and make it navigateable via a `ICollection<Food> Food` property inside the `recipe` class?

Second questions if the first one is possible: Will the `Foods` property contain the same `food` multiple times, when it is in multiple `ingredients` of the same `recipe`?

Thanks in advance!

---

### EDIT

As David Browne pointed out, this feature is currently not supported in EF core.

So I got a new question: Is it possible to define a `ICollection<Ingredients>` property on the `recipe` entity, which uses the already existing relationship definitions?

I already thought of:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>()
  .HasMany(recipe => recipe.Ingredients)
  .WithOne(ingredient => ingredient.Recipe)
  .UsingEntity<Step>();
```

But this won't work

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is called a "Direct Many-to-Many Relationship", but with two levels of linking tables.  This is a mapping scenario that EF doesn't (yet) support.  See [Relationshps - EF Core - Many to Many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

You can always use "Indirect Many-to-Many" with the existing relationships.

```
from r in db.Recipes
select new 
{ 
  Recipe=r, 
  Foods = r.Steps.SelectMany(s => s.Ingredients).Select(i => i.Food).ToList()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That "Direct Many-to-Many Relationship" are not supporting yet is a bit disappointing, but explains why I had such a hard time getting it to work.
I already configured the n:n relationship between `step` and `food` and can access the food via a property in `step`. But this will not help, right?

Comment: Is there a feature request on github, where I can track the status of this feature?